# aws php file upload size limit increase

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my backend on a default php elastic beanstalk instance on AWS and was wondering how do I increase the post_max_size and upload_file_size limit. I've tried on my local machine but the Laravel ValidatePostSize middleware says that its still 8M not 100M, but even if I change my local how do I change my elastic beanstalk instance.

Comment: did you deploy your app via the Elastic Beanstalk CLI? or via the console?

Comment: unfortunately its manually with the aws upload and zipping up my project

Comment: note updated instructions...

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed your app via the console, then follow these steps to change your elastic beanstalk app to a new version via the console:

1. Zip your development environment (with the increased limits on post_max_size and upload_file_size).  This should be the same code base that was initially released.
2. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
3. Navigate to the management page for your environment.
4. Choose Upload and Deploy.

[image]

5. Choose Browse to select the application source bundle you zipped in step 1.
6. Type a unique Version label to represent the new application version. (ie 'Laravel-increased-limits')
7. Choose Deploy.

Reference the [official AWS instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html#deployments-newversion) here.